# socket.io - Basic example usage error, io not defined error

Tags: firefox, socket.io

I am running node v0.5.11 pre
and installed socket.io. I have also install socket.io version 0.9.1

I am running server standard.

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8080);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
    socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

which is standard server and following is client ..

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io.connect('171.69.117.215:8080');
    socket.on('news', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
    });
</script>
```

when I load client in Firefox using port 80 from server 171.69.117.215 I get in Firebug following error:

> io is not defined
> [Break On This Error]
>
> var socket = io.connect('171.69.117.215:8080');

I know it is deployment issue as I am loading from port 80 client, which is right way to deploy socket.io application ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Please insert into client code ..Point to your on node.js server.

```
       <script src="http://yournodeserver/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```